# "i" virar um botão HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, eu gostaria que o meu 'i' do html virasse um botão, pois a partir dele eu quero chamar um modal, eu quero usar um 'i' pois quero colocar o icone do facebook, eu tentei colocar dentro do botão, mas não atingiu o design que eu quero.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#facebookModal">
                                        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                                    </button>
```

Gostaria que tivesse apenas o 'i' e a partir dele chamasse o modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/okXadcFuFIuqQndXnfTW?p=preview)

```
<i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#facebookModal" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fab fa-facebook"></span>
</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso utilize algum framework js (angular, vuejs) poderia apenas apensar a função junto ao I.
Como no exemplo não fica claro qual a abordagem, uma delas seria:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" >
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>

</div>
```